# How to get a list of sound notifications?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building an app where the users can choose the notification sounds inside the app.

The app would display a List of all notification sound that are inside the smartphone.

**The Question:**

*How can I get a list of all notification sounds from the users phone, so the user can choose the preferable sound?*

Is there any package in pub.dev or any way to do this (Android & iOS)?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not extensively available. But there is a work around, and that is:

> 1. Have a button
> 2. On press of that, open up your `Sound and Vibration Settings`.
> 3. Let the user choose from there itself

For that you can use [app_settings](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/app_settings) package.

This is simple representation of *how you can open up your `location settings` on press of a button*

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
                onPressed: AppSettings.openLocationSettings(), // here is the magic
                child: Text('Open Location Settings'),
            ),
        ],
    );
}
```

Consider this as an option. If you don't find anything, you can come back to it, and make use of it :)

Comment: thank you for the recommendation, but im currently looking to get a list of system sounds in my app :)

Comment: Got it. But this is kinda complex. If you don't find any thing, you might wanna look for the workarounds :) All the best @x98

Answer (score 0):

First thing there is no plugins available which are fit into your requirement.

**For `iOS` & `Android`, It is mandatory to keep sound file inside your project to play custom sound when notification received.**

You need to get a list of the available sound file inside your project and load it to the widget.

Thanks.

Comment: so it is impossible to retrieve a list of system sounds in iOS and Android using Flutter?

Comment: No, It is possible but you need to do more workout for this.

Comment: should i write native (Swift & Java) code to achieve this or is it achievable even by using Dart & Flutter?

Comment: Can do it by the flutter code, You just need to create list of sound url and use it accordingly